# Basic data storage in python

Tags: python

I need to store the user data input into a specific folder in txt.format.

so this is my code (e.g)

```
saving = input( "enter your saving" )

week = saving * 7
```

how to save the "week" into a specific folder?

Comment: Check http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Comment: Stackoverflow is here for the more difficult questions / problems. Not for a programming 101. Thats what we have Google for. Next time, try to search for your answer before asking a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to do it.

```
saving = int(input( "enter your saving" ))
week = saving * 7 

with open('give file path here', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(week))
```